# GWT + Spring Security = Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler

Tags: gwt, spring-security

I have a clean GWT application which I want to secure with Spring Security.  I have a standard filter configuration in web.xml and a standard form-based security configuration in my Spring context file.

When I build my application as a .war and deploy it to an app server it works as expected, however when I try to run it in the GWT Jetty server within Eclipse I get the dreaded `Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler` exception because of the `security` namespace.

I know that this is usually due to a missing spring-security-config library, but I am certain that all my requisite Spring Security libraries are on the classpath.  Is there something I'm missing about how the GWT Eclipse plugin server handles class loading?

I have tried every combination I can think of to manually add the Spring Security .jars to my project build path, my run configuration path, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the GWT Eclipse plugin server does not respect the Eclipse project classpath settings.  When I manually copy the spring-security .jars into `WEB-INF/lib` and run a `GWT Compile`, everything works as expected.